# Cannot run a simple PHP file on the server

Tags: php

Hi have uploaded a PHP file on the server.  When reaching that url using a browser, for example

```
mysite.com/test.php
```

I see the code (content) of the PHP file and the script seems not running.

SERVER IS F5 BIG-IP Apache

Could you point me out what could be the error?

```
<?php

$url = rawurldecode($_GET['proxy_url']);
$cb = ! empty($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;

if(preg_match('#xxx\.xxx\.com/xxx/#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#http\://xxx\.xxx\.com/xxx/#', '', $url);
}

if(! preg_match('#^https?:#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#^[\.\/]+#', '', $url);

    if(!file_exists($url)){
        echo 'File not found';
        die(0);
    }
}

if(preg_match('#\.xml$#', $url)){
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
}

$file = file_get_contents($url);

if($cb){
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo $cb.'('.$file.');';

}else{
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: Server does not support PHP.

Comment: What code did you post? Did it start with `<?php`?

Comment: See that entire list of dupes -->

Comment: Better you post some code here.

Comment: seems like your server is not configure to process php. What server do you use?

Comment: Do you use <?php ?> tag ?

Comment: You need to close it with `?>`

Comment: @fedorqui no you do not

Comment: yes script include <?php

Comment: Could you please add a comment if you have down-voted? SO I would be keen to improve my question. Unfortunately I do not know PHP.. maybe the question to trivial?

Comment: as i said earlier, probably server is not configured for php. You have not answered what server you used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated my question with the server I am using F5 BIG-IP Apache

Comment: is your server on linux? This is one of the guides to install php on apache server: [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/516.cfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed PHP? - If so do the following:

1. Start off by trying a simple script - call it say info.php:
2. Ensure (assuming Apache) that you have it the web server configured - see http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

If all this works then there is a problem with the script.

Answer (score 0):

close php tag and check does server support php

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not setup to parse PHP scripts, check that it has PHP installed